# JNR UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, ffi, unsatisfiedlinkerror, jnr

This question might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823870/jna-unsatisfiedlinkerror-but-jna-library-path-is-set#10281950) and a ton other UnsatisfiedLinkError questions.

I'm trying to run the following code.

```
import jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader;
import jnr.ffi.types.pid_t;

/**
 * Gets the process ID of the current process, and that of its parent.
*/
public class Getpid {
    public interface LibC  {
        public @pid_t long getpid();
        public @pid_t long getppid();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LibC libc = (LibC) LibraryLoader.create(LibC.class).load("c");

        System.out.println("pid=" + libc.getpid() + " parent pid=" + libc.getppid());
    }
}
```

The code compiles correctly but refuses to run,

(compilation step)

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/jnr-ffi.jar:. Getpid.java
```

(running step)

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/jnr-ffi.jar:. Getpid
```

While running I get this [error](http://lpaste.net/354151).

Comment: It can't find the requested class. See the root cause down at the bottom in your stacktrace

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to install objective-web's asm.jar
- and jjfi.jar
- add those to your classpath and voila!

Compile with this:

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/jnr-ffi.jar:.:/usr/lib/java/jffi.jar:/usr/lib/java/jffi-native.jar:/usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm.jar Getpid.java
```

and run with this:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/jnr-ffi.jar:.:/usr/lib/java/jffi.jar:/usr/lib/java/jffi-native.jar:/usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm.jar Getpid
```